# How do I merge people on Ancestry.com?

Tags: ancestry.com

I've noticed this awkward scenario with Ancestry.com

[image: Picture of Ancestry.com tree]

Obviously Lewis Caplan and Louis Caplan are the same people. How do I merge them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to say so but as of now, there is no such option available in Anchestry.com. Also, having no API, you cannot add the option yourself.

The only way out here is to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by following the instructions provided [here](http://help.ancestry.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5537/~/merging-duplicate-individuals-in-an-ancestry-member-tree). Basically:

1. From the profile page of the individual in your tree, select the **Tools** tab located in the top right corner of the page and select **Merge with Duplicate** from the drop-down list
2. [image]
3. On the Merge Duplicate People page you will see two columns. The left column, or the **Person 1** column, contains the information for the person you previously selected. In the right column, or the **Person 2** column, will be several option that will assist you in locating the duplicate individual that you would like to merge.
   [image]
4. If you have a person in your tree that is recognized by the system as a duplicate, that individual will be listed on the right automatically. If it is the individual that you wanted to merge, click the green **SELECT** button.
   **Note:** We'll suggest individuals who might be duplicates if they have the same first and last names and their birth years and birth places are similar.
   [image]
5. If you do not have an automatic match or need to merge a different person, you can manually select an individual to merge. Type the name of the individual into the field on the right and select their name from the drop-down list.
   [image]
6. Once you have selected your second individual to merge, you will now be presented with a side-by-side comparison of the two individuals you selected and you will not be able to choose which facts you want to display for the merged individual. Make your selections by clicking the radio buttons directly to the right of each fact.
   [image]

   - **If the facts are identical**: A same label shows which facts are the same; they'll be merged into one fact.
   - **If the facts are different**: Both facts will be included in the merge, but you can choose which fact is preferred (the default fact displays). The other fact will be added as an alternate.
     **Note**: If you are not sure which fact to make preferred, click the green Compare button above the comparison columns to view more details about the two individuals.
7. When you have completed your selections, click the orange **MERGE** button.
   **Note**: If the newly merged individual has duplicate relatives they do not merge automatically, you will need to repeat this process for each person,